# Adding a legend and dividing the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following reproducible code.

- How can I add a legend to this plot to show that the red curve represents y and the green curve represents z?
- How can I divide the plot into 8 sections as the following:
  A = 4 to 9 , B= 10 to 15 , C= 16 to 21 , D = 1,2,3,22,23 and 24 , AA= 28 to 33 , BB= 24 to 39 , CC= 40 to 45 and DD= 25, 26 , 27, 46, 47 and 48

My code is here :

```
require(ggplot2)
x <- 1:48
y <- rnorm(length(x))
z <- rnorm(length(x))
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = y), colour = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = z), colour = "green")
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand how D and DD correspond to a "section" when their values are discontinuous? And I think `BB` is supposed to be 34-39?

Comment: It's about adding labels (A,B,...) on the right places on the X axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a colour scale across the bottom of the plot to indicate the sections. Something like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:48, y = rnorm(48), z = rnorm(48),
                  section = c(rep("D", 3), rep("A", 6), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 6), 
                              rep("D", 3), rep("DD", 3), rep("AA", 6), rep("BB", 6), 
                              rep("CC", 6), rep("DD", 3))

df1 %>% 
  gather(var, val, -x, -section) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, val)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = var, group = var)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green")) + 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = x, xmax = lead(x), ymin = -Inf, ymax = min(val), fill = section)) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

You could even fill the background by section, but then I'd use linetype instead of colour to distinguish the lines.

```
df1 %>%  
  gather(var, val, -x, -section) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, val)) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype = var, group = var)) + 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = x, xmax = lead(x), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = section), 
              alpha = 0.2, show.legend = FALSE) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

x <- 1:48
y <- rnorm(length(x))
z <- rnorm(length(x))
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

df <- gather(df, 'y', 'z', key = "group", value = "value")

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = value, color = group)) +
geom_line() +
scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "green"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what definition of splitting the plot you mean, but this answers your second question, if you want it to look like this:

[image: A faceted plot]

```
# Converts numbers from 1 to 48 into one of (A, AA, B, ... D, DD)
codify <- function(value) {
         c(
           rep('D', 3),  #  1 to 3 
           rep('A', 6),  #  4 to 9
           rep('B', 6),  # 10 to 15
           rep('C', 6),  # 16 to 21
           rep('D', 3),  # 22 to 24
           rep('DD', 6), # 25 to 27
           rep('AA', 6), # 28 to 33
           rep('BB', 6), # 34 to 39 (I'm assuming you meant BB goes from 34)
           rep('CC', 6), # 40 to 45 (I'm assuming you meant BB goes from 34)
           rep('DD', 3)  # 46 to 48 (I'm assuming you meant BB goes from 34)
           )[value]
}


require(ggplot2)
x <- 1:48
y <- rnorm(length(x))
z <- rnorm(length(x))
type <- codify(x)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z, type)

ggplot(df,
       aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=y),colour="red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=z),colour="green") +
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, The thing I am looking for is not having multiple plots. I am looking for a way to just add the labels of (A, B, ...) on the right places on the X axis.